# Docker container with git-daemon keeps stopping

Tags: git, docker, daemon, git-daemon

Not sure whether it's my misunderstanding of docker, git-daemon, general linux-fu or all of the above, but having set up one inside the other I'm noticing that the container will run for around 20 seconds, then just exit.

- I set up a simple dockerfile, to install git, git-daemon-run and a git user.
- I then `USER: git` and the entrypoint runs the daemon with `--base-path` set to the user's home directory.
- Call `docker run` with the `-d` flag.
- Check every few seconds on container with `docker ps`.
- Everything is fine for a few checks, then suddenly the container is stopped.

Steps taken:

- Running `docker logs ...` shows: `error: waitpid for git-daemon failed: No child processes`. But googling that doesn't get me very far.
- Read `git-daemon` doesn't run *as* a daemon by default so amended the entrypoint to include `--detach` but that just means the container doesn't stay alive at all and the logs are empty.
- Run container with `-it` instead of `-d` and I observe the same behaviour.
- Use `docker exec` to init a repo inside the container to give the daemon "something to share" but still shuts down.

I had been playing around with this setup previously and I thought it had been working. What am I missing, not following?

**Update:**

The exit code given for the container is (128) which I'm struggling to find documentation on. Best I have is that `128 + n` Is fatal signal error `n` but under the man page for signal I can't find signal 0.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install git 
RUN apt-get -y install git-daemon-run
EXPOSE 9418

RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash git && chown -R git:git /home/git

USER git
WORKDIR /home/git

ENTRYPOINT [ "git", "daemon", "--base-path=/home/git", "--export-all", "--reuseaddr", "--enable=receive-pack" ]
```

Docker build & run commands:

```
docker build -t git-daemon . -f ./dockerfiles/git.daemon.dockerfile
docker create network docknet-0
docker run --name gitsrv -d --network=docknet-0 -p 9418:9418 git-daemon
```

**Update:**

The problem would appear to be related to running the docker engine as rootless. The container will only stay alive so long as the user I'm using to run the engine (in my case docker/1001) is logged into the system. If I SSH in as this user the container does not stop but the `waitpid` error is triggered when I terminate the connection. Changing the user within the container (i.e. leaving that as `root` instead of `git`) doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Please update your question to include a `Dockerfile` that will reproduce the behavior you're asking about. Without that, all we can do is guess.

Comment: Sorry, had to clean it up since I tend to saturate with comments while learning the ropes. Have edited my post. I included the network command I'm using just in case it's related.